# How to free storage besides clearing up cache memory

Tags: applications, samsung, storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Samsung galaxy smart phone. Whenever I download apps such as,Ubber and Facebook it tells me that my storage is full. I have cleared up cache memory but still there is no difference. What can I do?

Comment: Remove photos/videos/music? Delete downloads and documents?

Comment: Some cleaning apps (like CCleaner) have a function to clear the hidden/system cache (which can be up to several GB), you could try that.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You could check with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for a starter :)

Comment: Uninstall updates and disable apps which are installed but can't be deleted and you don't use it. Eg some Google apps. Edit: what is storage capacity of your device?

Answer (score 2):

[Disk usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en) - view whats really eating up your storage

[SD maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) - file cleaner

[Files Go - by google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) - leave it installed and it will automatically remind you what unused files to delete

[Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos) - backup every photo and select free up storage to delete already backed up images and videos

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall some Apps
- Delete some data (e.g Photos, Videos)
- Install a cleaner that has a Deep-Cleaning Feature